# how to cut transparent part from photo with command or shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command

I am having trouble to cut photos in the command line. I need to cut transparent part of a photo and save with command line or shell script
Thanks beforehand. If I could do it I would apply it for 4000 photos and it would be a great help
More clear explanation what I want to do
I have a png picture like this

[image]

I want to have an image like this

[image]

I could make the image transparent only and is there any way to cut bottom transparent part from a png file

Beforehand thank you very much

Comment: why you want to do it using shell script

Comment: Is there any option to apply it for 4000 png files, I guess script does it very vast

Comment: Can you please share an example of what you are trying to do? As Mark said "It's hard without seeing your images"... Well, there are many options to play with images. Moreover, the number does not matter. If you can do it for one it can be done for any number.

Comment: Okay sir, Thanks for your great effort, I think I have uploaded some pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having that Mark Setchell's Imagemagick command overlooked (probably because he did not have your image at the time) is the orange scroll bar in the lower right corner. You must change the orange to white and then trim as per Mark's suggestion. Your image has an alpha channel but it is fully opaque and so can be removed, also.

```
convert input.png -alpha off -fuzz 10% -fill white -opaque "rgb(241,144,105)" -trim +repage output.png
```

[image]

Note that using too large a fuzz value will also change the color of the red button in the top right corner to white. So -fuzz 10% seems to be a good compromise.

Comment: Hi, I am sooooo glad to see the solution, it was a life saver. Thank you very very very much. I cannot express how it was helpful. Thanks it solved my problem

Answer (score 6):

It's hard without seeing your images, but you can try with **ImageMagick** as follows:

```
convert input.png -trim +repage output.png
```

and see if that works. If it nearly works, try:

```
convert input.png -fuzz 25% -trim +repage output.png
```

If it works, make a backup and then do them all with **GNU Parallel**:

```
find . -name \*.png -print0 | parallel -0 mogrify -trim +repage {}
```

Comment: Thank you for effort, but it did not work as I suppose, it is removing white background which what I could only do. I want to do as shown in the second picture
I want to cut blank white part of the picture from photo to have only information written on ) Again thanks for your consideration

Comment: Please provide the actual input image rather than a picture of it in an editor with other images and annotations around it. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how my command can remove white background when your image doesn't have a white background?

Comment: Yes, fine. I updated my answer, please try new version first.

Comment: Could you see the photos uploaded, I want to implement such thing, I saw it was possible with javascript but it would be better with shell script or command)

Comment: I don't get it. Your image of a directory listing in a Terminal doesn't have any transparent parts in it, so how can I cut transparent parts? It also doesn't have any white background, so I don't see how my command can be cutting white background?

Comment: Okay thanks for your try, I guess I could not explain well what I mean
Sorry for taking your time

Comment: It's no problem, I am happy to keep trying, I just don't understand yet what you want. Your example is a solid, opaque Terminal listing but the instructions are to trim a stick man on a transparent canvas. Please just click `edit` under your question and describe what the result will look like and I will try again.